# Why and by whom is this method called in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I make my first steps with kivy and try to plot functions entered in a TextInput via matplotlib or pygal. Both works fine as long as I save the images on the disk. To speed up the program I don't want the image write to and read from the disk. I found this following solution on [mornie.org](https://mornie.org/blog/2013/11/06/how-load-image-memory-kivy/):

```
class MemoryImage(Image):
    """Display an image already loaded in memory."""
    memory_data = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, memory_data, **kwargs):
            super(MemoryImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            self.memory_data = memory_data

    def on_memory_data(self, *args):
            """Load image from memory."""
            data = StringIO.StringIO(self.memory_data)
            with self.canvas:
                    self.texture = ImageLoaderPygame(data).texture
```

By randomly changing words until it runs under python3 I found this solution:

```
class MemoryImage(Image):
    """Quelle: https://mornie.org/blog/2013/11/06/how-load-image-memory-kivy/"""
    memory_data = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,memory_data,**kwargs):
            """Display an image already loaded in memory."""
            super(MemoryImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.memory_data = memory_data

    def on_memory_data(self, *args):
            """Load image from memory."""
            data = BytesIO(self.memory_data)
            with self.canvas:
                    self.texture = ImageLoaderPygame(filename="test.png",rawdata=data, ext="png", inline=True).texture
```

This solution works well as long as I don't try to update the image. Unfortunately this is my intention. So I try to understand this class. But I can't - and in front I am a raw recruit in OOP - find a single point where this on_memory_data method is called. First I searched the parents of this class, then I grep the kivy and finally my whole /usr folder for python files containing 'on_memory', but there is nothing.

I would be thankful if anybody could give me a hint, why this method is called!

Comment: what's the size of the image?

Comment: 640x480! (some extra characters to submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_memory_data` is called when the `memory_data` ObjectProperty changes (i.e. when the object it references is replaced, it doesn't know about internal changes of the object). This is an automatic behaviour of kivy properties.

Comment: Got it. I was lost in the API Documentation. Now I found this point in the guide http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event